# What PATH env to include in heroku for ImageMagick?

Tags: node.js, heroku, imagemagick

I am trying to use imagemagick and installed it and included it in heroku but I am getting this error which from what I researched points to the PATH missing, so I am trying to figure out how to add it in heroku?

This is the error:

```
 Error: spawn ENOENT
```

So far I installed the build packs like so:

```
heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi
```

then including these buildpacks in .buildpacks

```
https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs
```

I tried including the PATH but not sure what path needs to be included by adding vendor/imagemagick with export...

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334920/heroku-buildpacks-installing-executables-that-are-used-by-python-packages

Answer (score 0):

Run `heroku run bash` and then try different combinations paths like `PATH='/bin' imagemagick` until you get the one that works. Then use config:set to set it permanently. And, please post the answer back here.

Comment: Ok, I tried bin and a bunch of others but was getting the same error, the issue is I am not sure what path to include.