# How to use tesseract in heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, tesseract, python-tesseract, buildpack

I wanna know how to use pytesseract in Heroku, I installed using pip install but when, I put path it gives error. I tried using Build packs too but I can't get path. please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1: with build packs

The build pack executables are in the $INSTALL_DIR directory.

Take a look at this question [Heroku buildpacks - installing executables that are used by Python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334920/heroku-buildpacks-installing-executables-that-are-used-by-python-packages) to customize your path in a build pack (just clone the build pack git and change your PATH).

#### Option 2: With custom docker image

Another option is to build your own docker image with based in the official python docker image (ie python:3.8-buster) and install tesseract.

You can use this dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tesseract-ocr-all 

RUN mkdir /home/work
WORKDIR /home/work
```

Once you have this docker image, you can push it to heroku private docker registry and use it to run your dynos.

Comment: Thanks but what if I don't wanna use docker?